# grep: /etc/wsl.conf: no such file or directory --- ERROR

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, atom-editor

I have windows machine and i am using ubuntu on windows 10 app for linux. I want to integrate this app with atom editor.
whenever i am hitting atom . command  on ubuntu on windows 10 terminal its giving me error saying that :

grep: /etc/wsl.conf: no such file or directory
'\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\myhomedirectory'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
'esources'is not recognised as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft article
[Automatically Configuring WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/)
describes this file:

> Beginning with Insider Build 17093, we added a method for you to automatically configure certain functionality in WSL that will be applied every time you launch the subsystem.
> [..]
> If the file is not there, you can create it yourself. WSL will detect the existence of the file and will read its contents. If the file is missing or malformed (that is, improper markup formatting), WSL will continue to launch as normal.

I don't know why your program is trying to read this file, but you can
create it as an empty file using the command:

```
sudo touch /etc/wsl.conf
```